# Enviar datos mediante POST a página de terceros

Tags: php, web

¿Cómo puedo pasar valores mediante POST o GET pero a otra página, que no sea mia?

Por Ejemplo:
Tengo la pagina A mia, y quiero enviarle datos a la página B pero esta es de otro dominio, otro dueño.

Ya se los campos del formulario de la página B pero no sé cómo enviárselos desde la página A.

Comment: Si redireccionas a la otra pagina con los parametros que deseas, la otra pagina debe de obtenerlo sin ningun tipo de problema.

Comment: Qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza **CURL** para realizar transacciones a sitios externos, ten en cuenta algunos puntos:

- Debes conocer todos los atributos a enviar
- Como no tienes el control del otro sitio, este método podría no funcionar, debido a atributos tipo hidden o efectos de comprobación de sesiones.
- Tener en cuenta que es lo que vas a recibir como respuesta si se realiza la transacción.

Algunos sitios funcionan con diferentes tecnologías, asi que hay que realizar pruebas si este es un método funcional.

Un ejemplo básico:

```
// atributos a enviar mediante post, pueden ser cualquier otros
$post = [
    'user' => 'user1',
    'pass' => 'pass1'
];

//url de la pagina externa
$ch = curl_init('http://www.example.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

// executar y obtener la repuesta
$response = curl_exec($ch);

//recoger errores por si falla
$error = curl_error($ch);

// cerrar la conexión o sesiones
curl_close($ch);

// puedes hacer lo que sea con la respuesta o el error
var_dump($response);
echo $error;
```

> [Curl en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/curl.examples-basic.php)

Answer (score 0):

tienes muchas metodologias de enviar data a un server externo ajax, php en fin te dejo un ejemplo:

```
<?php
function hacer_post_externo($url, $data, $headers = null)
{
  $params = array('http' => array(
              'method' => 'POST',
              'content' => $data
            ));
  if (headers !== null) {
    $params['http']['header'] = $headers;
  }
  $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
  $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
  if (!$fp) {
    throw new Exception("Problema con: $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
  if ($response === false) {
    throw new Exception("Problema al leer data de : $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  return $response; /* tu resultado en caso exitoso */
}
```

**con ajax**

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://www.ejemplo.com/algo.php",
data:data, //data a enviar
type: "POST"
}).done(function(result) {
//resultado
console.log(result);
});
```

como te comentaba es solo un ejemplo hay muchas formas !! suerte !